# Modify the text of boundfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a gridview :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReportingListeOF" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Visible="false">

<Columns>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="cod_wo" HeaderText="N° OF" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="cod_ref" HeaderText="Référence article" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="lbl_article" HeaderText="Désignation article" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="dat_sequence_wo" HeaderText="Séquence" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="wo_qty" HeaderText="Qté prévue" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="qty_revue" HeaderText="Qte revue" />

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

And I wish changing dynamically the header text with code behind C#. It is possible ? Because they doesn't have ID...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the above

```
gvReportingListeOF.Columns[ColumnIndex].HeaderText = "Header text"
```

Comment: Thanks, I thinks this is the solution ;)

Comment: @user2265252 Your are welcome. Mark as accepted the solution then :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the code in the RowDataBound Event like this.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
  e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "First Column";
  e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Second Column";
}
```